# Sentry 2 and Laravel 4 adding fields to the user model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, frameworks, cartalyst-sentry

Im trying to add fields to the Users model that is based around Sentry 2 for Laravel 4.

I want to do it properly with migrations.

Is there a way to simply add to the sentry 2 migrations? or should i simply make my own migrations and add the required extra fields?

any guidance with the framework would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of migrations is **versioning** of the database structure. The answer to any question similar to "where should I put database changes?" is always: "in a new migration", because then you're able to rollback changes.

In this case, I think I would first add Sentry 2 to your project and commit "Added Sentry 2". After, I would create a new migration with your desired changes, then commit: "Added fields x y and z to Users table".

See also the introduction paragraph of the documentation: http://four.laravel.com/docs/migrations

Comment: A little clearer explanation then my own.. so you get the lucky tick

Answer (score 11):

If you want add some fields you need this:

- run Sentry Migrations: `php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry`
- create a migration to add custom fields to Users table: `php artisan migrate:make --table=users`
- example in funcion up():

`Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->string('new_field');
});`

- And then extend the Sentry User Model:

Check this [example](https://github.com/bstrahija/l4-site-tutorial/blob/master/app/models/User.php) is extending Sentry Model and full implementation example check this: [Laravel 4 Backend and simple web site](http://www.codeforest.net/laravel4-simple-website-with-backend-1)

Comment: Worked perfectly but only one small mistake, you need to add table name "php artisan migrate:make users --table=users" rest of is pefect

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is simple navigate to the actual sentry migration file found at

vendor/cartalyst/sentry/src/migrations

copy the needed migrations out and create your own migrations file.

There is no other way. Just me being lazy i guess.